# symfony2 and doctrine2 : show the names of my list tables in my view

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, php-5.3

i have just a little problem in my controller file , just i want to display the names of list tables in my template ...this is the code in my controller

```
namespace Sftn\TestBundle\Controller;
namespace Sftn\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table;

class PageSearchController extends Controller
{
    public function SearchElementAction()
    { 
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $conn= $em->getConnection();
        $sm = $conn->getSchemaManager();
        $tables = $sm->listTableNames();
        return $this->render('SftnTestBundle:Search:searchElement.html.twig', array('name'=>print_r($tables,true)));
    }
}
```

and this is my template file

```
<body>
    <table><tr><td>{{name}}</td></tr></table>
</body>
```

and this is my view

**Array ( [0] => consi [1] => enquiry [2] => formule [3] => formule_2g_ancien [4] => formule_3g [5] => formule_brut [6] => formule_global [7] => fos_user [8] => huawei_counter_list_2g [9] => huawei_counter_list_3g [10] => huawei_description_parameter [11] => huawei_parameter_list_2g [12] => huawei_parameter_list_3g [13] => nom_ind [14] => nsn_counter_list_2g [15] => nsn_counter_list_3g [16] => nsn_parameter_list_2g [17] => nsn_parameter_list_3g [18] => type_tech [19] => users )**

but , i don't want the display of my name tables like this i want them Display like this

1. consi
2. enquiry
3. formule
4. formule_2g_ancien
5. formule_3g

and all the talbles like this display

i need help and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, return the table of 'tables names'

```
return $this->render('SftnTestBundle:Search:searchElement.html.twig', array('tables'=> $tables));
```

and in your twig

```
{% for table in tables %}
    {{ loop.index }}. {{ table }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT:

If you want to filter your tables, do it in your controller:

```
$tablesResult = array();
foreach($tables as $table){
    if(preg_match('/.*_[23]g$/', $table)){
        $tableResult[] = $table;
    }
}
return $this->render('SftnTestBundle:Search:searchElement.html.twig', array('tables'=> $tablesResult));
```

Comment: thank you @VBee for you answer but i test your answer and i get this error in my view **Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "," ("end of statement block" expected) in SftnTestBundle:Search:searchElement.html.twig at line 36**

Comment: i find the solution just i edit the twig file and make it like this `{% for table in tables %}
{{ table }}<br/>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: if you can help me more please , i want to filter my tables juste i want to display in my view  some tables not all , what i will do ?

Comment: juste i want to dislay this names table in my view **formule formule_2g_ancien  formule_3g   huawei_counter_list_2g huawei_counter_list_3g  huawei_description_parameter huawei_parameter_list_2g huawei_parameter_list_3g   nsn_counter_list_2g  nsn_counter_list_3g nsn_parameter_list_2g nsn_parameter_list_3g**

Comment: do it in your controller method with a conditional statement

Comment: i'm sorry @VBee but i don't understand you clearly ...can you explain for me more !!